# multiplying sampler lookups glsl

Tags: glsl

I pass a 1D array as sampler1D and a 2D array (basically a matrix) as sampler2D to my vertex shader.
Everything works fine - i checked the values, every value is where it should be.
BUT - I can't seem to multiply two values of those samplers with each other.

```
    float pos=0.0;
    vec4 f = texture1D(xk,ki);
    vec4 H = texture2D(er,vec2(0,i));

    pos=f[0]*H[0];
    colorcheck=pos;
```

I pass colorcheck to my fragment shader, but it won't render my object, instead everything is just black (passing colorcheck=1.0 works fine). I checked both vectors after the lookup - both have valid values in all fields.

I've tried f.x*H.x, and all combinations I can think of.. I even tried multiplying in the fragment shader - won't work either..

EDIT
simplified vertex shader (doesnt work either/works when I pass colorcheck=1.0/f.x/H.x.. anything)

```
    uniform sampler1D xk;
    uniform sampler2D eigenraum;
    varying float colorcheck;
    void main(){
       vec4 f = texture1D(xk,0);
       vec4 H = texture2D(eigenraum,vec2(0,0));
       colorcheck=f[0]*H[0];
       gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
   }
```

and fragment shader:

```
varying float colorcheck;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor=vec4(colorcheck,1,1,1.0);
}
```

Thanks for your help!

EDIT2 - turns out I can't substract/add them either..

Comment: Can you put a little more background, and post a complete vertex and fragment shader pair that exhibit this? How do you verify that f and H are valid? Where is colorcheck going?

Comment: colorcheck is a varying float. In the fragment shader it looks like this gl_FragColor=vec4(colorcheck,1,1,1); - so when the values are as expected I just said if(f.x==0.5)colorcheck=1.0. and the color was white, as it should be (my way of debugging shaders, glslDevil doesn't work.

Comment: and the vertex shader is just a loop which should multiply those entries, I just check the outcome with colorcheck - the fragment shader is just gl_FragColor=vec4(colorcheck,1,1,1);

Comment: Please put real, complete shader in your question. In theory there should be no problem multiplying two numbers together. So obviously something else must be going wrong, perhaps it is something not being shown.

Comment: just added the shaders - btw, I can multiply/divide f.x or H.x with an arbitrary value.. just not with eachother.

Comment: cant answer my own question - sigh.. anyway I found the solution - it's not in the shader code.

I forgot the glActiveTexture call when binding the arrays to the textures!

Comment: Glad you fixed it. I posted your comment as a wiki answer, so that the question can be marked as solved.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution - it's not in the shader code. I forgot the glActiveTexture call when binding the arrays to the textures!